# SHA-256 suitable for password encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, sha256

I am implementing a user profile (registration) on my server where I have to store user accounts and passwords. I'm trying to store the password encrypted as a security measure and someone recommended that I use SHA-256.

I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to cryptography, but in a scenario where a hacker accesses my database and steals a whole bunch of encrypted passwords, isn't SHA-256 encryption vulnerable to known-plaintext attack? For instance, if they know what "password" gets hashed into, they'd just have to do a simple string match to know which accounts use that particular password.

Comment: SHA-256 is a hashing algorithm

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at pre-existing user management solutions for whichever platform you are developing on.  Most every modern platform has one.  If you are a beginner at cryptography, doubly so.

Comment: This is likely a common question on security.stackexchange.  [For example, this one might interest you](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough).

Comment: (a) If a hacker steals your database you are hosed anyway, but by hashing passwords they at least are still secure, and incidentally you don't lose non-repudiability. (b) What good is finding multiple accounts with the same password going to do anybody?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Off topic. In short, you need a PBKDF such as PBKDF2, with a 64 bit salt and high iteration count, and additional measures to ensure password quality, possibly a short static timeout after x attempts to slow down online brute force attacks.

Comment: Plain SHA-256 is not suitable for password hashing. While a salt prevents multi-target attacks, guessing attacks are quite efficient when executed with a GPU (or even worse, ASIC). That's why we use specialized password hashes as described at: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on security.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SHA-256 suitable for password encryption?

By itself, no. When used as a primitive with additional controls, yes.

> SHA-256 encryption vulnerable to known-plaintext attack? For instance, if they know what "password" gets hashed into, they'd just have to do a simple string match to know which accounts use that particular password.

That's a different security property :) Its called the PRP-notion of security and a hash lacks it. Dan Bohen has a good slide deck on it at [PRPs and PRFs](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/lectures/PRP-PRF.pdf).

A hash is a PRF (Pseudo Random Function). When using a hash, an attacker *can* distinguish between an oracle's real output and random output (as you observed).

A HMAC is also a PRF (Pseudo Random Function), and it holds the notion of PRP security because an attacker cannot distinguish between a real answer and a random answer when he/she queries the same oracle. The HMAC's key ensure it.

So, your first task is to use an HMAC based on SHA-256, and not SHA-256 directly :)

See the [Secure Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and [Secure Password Storage paper](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g) John Steven wrote for OWASP. It takes you through the entire threat model, and explains why things are done in particular ways.